# Google App Engine implementing GCM authentication for a "control panel"

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

So I have some solid experience programming games to which I want to add push notifications but I have very little web experience apart from html, css, and some lightweight php.

I've created and ran the example GCM server application in my Eclipse installation with Google plugins installed.

I wish to make a control panel for myself to send notifications and wish to allow only myself to login to obviously restrict public access. This doc page on Google only shows how to authenticate with a Google account, but it seems like any valid Google account that uses this auth will be able to access the GAE GCM server I am developing.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

Does anybody with GAE have any advice? Should I just allow Google Account authentication and then just serve control panel content only to accounts I specify or should I implement some "traditional" authentication. I don't myself know what "traditional" would be but I will research it if someone says authentication via Google Accounts and serving content to certified accounts is not wise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep authenticating with google accounts.
All that does is make sure the user is logged into their google account but doesnt validate beyond that. In your servlet use the User service to get the current user's email and if its not the one you want show/return an error.